# Windows Phone App scroll to top

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

Then I tap on textbox happen to scroll through on-screen keyboard did not close this textbox. If this `TextBox` move above, how i make auto-scroll page by top too? I tryed use `ScrollViewer`, and use his methods `InvalidateScrollInfo()` and `Scroll.UpdateLayout()` but page not moving. This xaml from my page:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroll">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Canvas>
                <TextBox x:Name="SearchTB" Width="200" Height="72" TextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged" Canvas.Left="112" Canvas.Top="297"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: could you ask someone to translate the question for you?

Comment: Sorry, maybe this will be clearer: If the screen is shifted to not close Textbox onscreen keyboard, and after that TextBox moved up, as have to browse the screen up without losing focus from the TextBox

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ScrollToVerticalOffset` on the parent ScrollViewer, with a parameter of 0 to scroll to the top.

Comment: I was trying:var sb = new Storyboard();
            sb.Completed += (o, args) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    Scroll.InvalidateScrollInfo();
                    Scroll.UpdateLayout();
                    Scroll.InvalidateScrollInfo();
                    Scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
                    Scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
                    Scroll.InvalidateScrollInfo();
                    Scroll.UpdateLayout();
                    Scroll.InvalidateScrollInfo();
                }); but page not scrolling.

Comment: You don't need to call any other junk except ScrollToVerticalOffset. If that doesn't work then you are probably scrolling the wrong container. Can you post the XAML?